# Executing child process in new terminal

Tags: c, sockets, unix, multiprocessing, unix-socket

I want to make a simple chat application for unix.
I have created one server which supports multiple clients. When ever a new client connects to the server a new process is created using fork command. Now the problem is all the child processes share the same stdin on the server, cause of this in order to send a message to 2nd clien 1st child prosess has to terminte. In order to resolve this I would like to run each child process in a new terminal. 
This can be achieved by writing the code for the child process code in a new file and executing it like xterm -e sh -c .(i have not tried this though).

What i really want is not to have two file just to fireup a new terminal and run rest of the code in it.

```
int say(int socket)
{
    char *s;
    fscanf(stdin,"%79s",s);
    int result=send(socket,s,strlen(s),0);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int listener_d;
    struct sockaddr_in name;
    listener_d=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    name.sin_family=PF_INET;
    name.sin_port=(in_port_t)htons(30000);
    name.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    int c = bind(listener_d,(struct sockaddr *)&name,sizeof(name)); //Bind
    if(c== -1)
    {
        printf("\nCan't bind to socket\n");
    }

    if(listen(listener_d,10) == -1) // Listen
    {
        printf("\nCan't listen\n");
    }
    puts("\nWait for connection\n");
    while(1)
    {
        struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
        unsigned int address_size = sizeof(client_addr);
        int connect_d = accept(listener_d, 
              (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr,&address_size); //Accept
        if(connect_d== -1)
        {
            printf("\nCan't open secondary socket\n");
        }

        if(!fork())
        {
            close(listener_d);
            char *msg = "welcome Sweetone\n";
            if(send(connect_d,msg,strlen(msg),0))
            {
                printf("send");
            }
            int k=0;
            while(k<5)
            {
                say(connect_d);
                ++k;
            }
            close(connect_d);
            exit(0);
        }
            close(connect_d);
    }
    close(listener_d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When reading from `stdin`, should that input be sent to all connected clients? Have you thought about threads instead of processes?

Comment: Yes this is a sample program. I definately will shift to threads. as far as the reading from stdin is concerned what happens is that the data from stdin goes to the 1st clien that connects once that terminated only then if u type anything it goes to the nest client.

Answer (score 1):

I think the message sending between your client and servers is a bit unusual. It is more common, in this simple "just test how it works" scenario to have the clients sending messages to the server. As an example I could mention a simple echo service, which mirrors everything a client sends, back to the client. Is this design forced by some requirements?

Critique aside, I have two separate changes that could make your current design work. They both involve changing the reading of input in the *subservers*.

Alternative 1:
Instead of reading from stdin, create a named pipe ( see `man 3 mkfifo`), fex /tmp/childpipe"pid_of_subserver_here". You could create the pipe in `say()` and open it for reading. Then use echo (`man echo`) to write to the pipe echo "My message" > /tmp/childpipe"NNNN". Before exiting the child, remember to remove the pipe with `unlink()`

Alternative 2:
Create an unnamed pipe between server and each subserver. This makes the code much more messy, but avoids creating named pipes and using echo. Example code is included below. It has insufficient error handling (like most example code) and does not handle disconnecting client properly.

Example usage: 1) start server ./a.out 2) (connect client in external window (e.g. nc localhost 30000) 3) write to client 1 by typing "1Hello client one" 4) (connect second client in third window etc) 4) Write to second client by typing "2Hello second client"

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

enum max_childeren{
    MAX_CHILDEREN = 50
};

int say(int socket)
{
    char buf[513] = {0};
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
    int result=send(socket, buf, strlen(buf),0);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int listener_d;
    struct sockaddr_in name;
    listener_d=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    name.sin_family=PF_INET;
    name.sin_port=(in_port_t)htons(30000);
    name.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    int on = 1;
    if (setsockopt(listener_d, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on)) < 0){
        perror("setsockopt()");
    }

    int c = bind(listener_d,(struct sockaddr *)&name,sizeof(name)); //Bind

    if(c== -1)
    {
        printf("\nCan't bind to socket\n");
    }

    if(listen(listener_d,10) == -1) // Listen
    {
        printf("\nCan't listen\n");
    }

    // Edited here
    int number_of_childeren = 0;
    int pipes[2] = {0};
    int child_pipe_write_ends[MAX_CHILDEREN] = {0};

    fd_set select_fds;
    FD_ZERO(&select_fds);

    puts("\nWait for connection\n");
    while(1)
    {
        struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
        unsigned int address_size = sizeof(client_addr);

        // Edited here, to multiplex IO
        FD_SET(listener_d, &select_fds);
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &select_fds);
        int maxfd = listener_d + 1;

        int create_new_child = 0;
        int connect_d = -1; // moved here

        select(maxfd, &select_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if (FD_ISSET(listener_d, &select_fds)){
            connect_d = accept(listener_d, 
                                   (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr,&address_size); //Accept
            if(connect_d== -1)
                {
                    printf("\nCan't open secondary socket\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

            create_new_child = 1;
        }

        char buf[512] ={0};
        char *endptr = NULL;
        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &select_fds)){
            fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
             long int child_num = strtol(buf, &endptr, 10);

             if (child_num > 0 && child_num <= number_of_childeren) {
                 write(child_pipe_write_ends[child_num - 1], endptr, strnlen(buf, sizeof(buf)) - (endptr - buf));
             }
             else {
                 printf("Skipping invalid input: %s\n", buf);
             }
        }

        if (create_new_child != 1)
            continue;

        number_of_childeren++; // Edited here

        int error = pipe(pipes);
        if (error != 0){
            //handle errors
            perror("pipe():");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        child_pipe_write_ends[number_of_childeren - 1] = pipes[1];

        if(!fork())
        {

            error = dup2(pipes[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            if (error < 0){ // could also test != STDIN_FILENO but thats confusing
                //handle errors
                perror("dup2");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            close(pipes[0]);

            close(listener_d);
            char *msg = "welcome Sweetone\n";
            if(send(connect_d,msg,strlen(msg),0))
            {
                printf("send\n");
            }
            int k=0;
            while(k<5)
            {
                say(connect_d);
                ++k;
            }
            close(connect_d);
            exit(0);
        }
            close(connect_d);
            close(pipes[0]);
    }
    close(listener_d);
    return 0;
}
```

The code needs refactoring into functions. It is too long. I tried to do the least possible amount of changes, so I left the restructuring as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks for tha amazing reply. Will definately get to learn a lot from the code once i analyse and understand it. I just read a few thing about socket programming and aimed to create my own terminal base p2p chat application (Havent researched on how a std p2p chat application is made.). That is why I wanted to open a new terminal when a client connects, like this i will have different window for every client and i can chat with them through these windows.  Let me know what else i can do to further in the intended direction. Thanks.

Comment: As online resources many favour [Beejs guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html). A book that will tell you almost everything you need and then some, is [UNIX Network Programming](http://www.kohala.com/start/unpv12e.html). A classic, though not only about network programming, is [APUE](http://www.apuebook.com/) and its modern Linux only equivalent [Linux Programming Interface](http://man7.org/tlpi/). To start with, I think Beejs Guide and reading man-pages for any unfamiliar library and system calls will be good.

Answer (score 0):

```
    fscanf(stdin,"%79s",s);
```

Why? Is it tcp-chat? You have some socket for each client and if yoy want to "say" something then you must to use client. It's true logick.

The server usually sends a service messages only. It's true logick too.

But if you want new terminal then you can try to use a exec's family from unistd.h .

Comment: hi, i replaced the code within the if(!fork()) block and placed it n a new filw (say function too). when i use system(./subserver listener_d connection_d) the sub program doesnt really work as intended. the clien doesnt receive any msg that i send from the server.

Comment: if I leave close(listener_d) where it is and place the rest of the code in the  if(!fork())  block in some other file the server goes beserk. I guess it forked many processes cause i couldnt use my machine after that since it was too busy.

Comment: I tried command like system("xterm -e .../subServer arg1 arg2"); the xterm becomes be the child process of my main server but not my subServer. And the functionality is not as intended.

Comment: Try to call execl("/bin/xterm","xterm","-e","%path_to_subprogram%","%socket_descriptor%") or something like this instead of "while(k<5)...".

Comment: execl("/usr/bin/xterm","xterm","-e","%path_to_subprogram%","%socket_descriptor%",NULL) of course. :)

Comment: while(k<5)... is just for the reason that server will send 5 messages to client from stdin and then break the connectin. execl will definately be a better replacement for system(), but i dont think it will resolve the real issue. Thanks

Comment: execl starts a new xterm process with non-blocked stdin (it's really true, i tried to do that some time ago) and child process must to inherit table of opened file descriptors of parent process. If you transmit socket descriptor to the child process as parameter, it can resolve your problem maybe. Just try it.