# Separate I/O for child process after fork()

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, posix

I am trying to implement an application on Linux using C, and I have a requirement that I need to do I/O separately on my child & parent process. Here is what I am looking for

1. User runs the application, the parent process spawns 3 child processes.
2. Each of the child process will spawn a thread that waits for the user input.
3. There should be an intuitive method by which the user can specify which of the child process he is interacting with.

Ideally I would like if each of the child processes is executed on different terminal, that way it is very clear to the user with whom he is interacting.

I saw a similar question in [Executing child process in new terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892182/executing-child-process-in-new-terminal), but the answer is not very clear regarding the steps involved. It seems to suggest that it can be done by execing the xterm like this `xterm -e sh -c`, but it is not confirmed. I would also want to setup some IPC between the parent <--> child & child <--> child process as well, so if I launch the child process in a new terminal by execing xterm, who is the child of my parent process? Is it xterm? If so, the code that I actually want to execute in my child process, will it get executed as a child of xterm?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have already spawned the three child processes and that you run your parent on tty1.

- tty1: Now contains all the diagnostics information
- tty2: Child process 1
- tty3: Child process 2
- tty4: Child process 3
- tty5: User input

So each child process will read from its tty as if it were a file (note: requires root permissions). To give input to, say, child process 2, go to tty5 and type in this command:
`cat - >/dev/tty3`

Then type in the input to your program, and then press Ctrl-D. Your child process 2 should now recieve that input.

EDIT You do not need to actually run the child processes on different ttys. It is only required to run them with root permissions and then read and write from those tty numbers, just as you would read from stdin and write to stdout. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `cat` terminates with EOF by default. And why would you use `tee` if you don't want output written to `stdout`? Your command line can be reduced to the equivalent (and shorter) form `cat >/dev/tty3`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, can you please elaborate how I will run the child process under different tty.